# Bash command to return a free port

Tags: bash, docker

As part of a build pipeline I would like to start containers with a free port.

Looking for something like this:

```
docker run --name frontend -p $(gimme-a-free-port):80 frontend:latest
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use port 0. Applications pass 0 to kernel and kernel assigns unused port to the application.

```
docker run --name frontend -p 0:80 frontend:latest
```

Or:

```
docker run --name frontend -p 80 frontend:latest
```

In second example I'm just specifying container port, Host port will be assigned automatically.

To verify:

```
docker port <containerid or container name>
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768
```

To get the random port value only:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "80/tcp") 0).HostPort }}' <containerid or container name>
32768
```

Comment: I would delete the second method. It can't reliably work since another process might have picked that port after your check but before docker can pick it. That's a classical race condition.

Comment: Yea thats true, but you can check the whole commands exit code and rerun if failed.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see any benefit from that.

Comment: removed the second method

Answer (score 2):

If you don't assign the host-port, docker will automatically pick a random port for publishing the container port.

For example;

```
$ docker run --name frontend -p 80 -dit busybox
4439bdce51eee473b1e961664839a410754157bf69da2d2545ab51528a42111c

$ docker port 4439bdce51eee473b1e961664839a410754157bf69da2d2545ab51528a42111c
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768

(or);

$ docker inspect -f '{{json .NetworkSettings.Ports}}' 4439bdce51eee473b1e961664839a410754157bf69da2d2545ab51528a42111c 
{"80/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"32768"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Container's External Port

```
PORT="$(docker ps|grep some_container|sed 's/.*0.0.0.0://g'|sed 's/->.*//g')"
```

Reference: https://blog.dcycle.com/snippet/2016-10-04/get-docker-container-port/